# If Logged In Member ID Working Except for One Member

Tags: members

Good Afternoon, I ran into a strange issue this morning. I have a page setup that contains a special link that I only want five specific members to have access too. I setup a conditional using the 'if logged_in_member_id' method for this link. It's working great except for the member with the ID of 10. My code is below. Any ideas why this would not work for just one of the members?

```
{if logged_in_member_id == "13" OR logged_in_member_id == "4" OR logged_in_member_id == "7" OR logged_in_member_id == "10" OR logged_in_member_id == "13"}<a href="/special-link">link</a>{/if}
```

Thanks in advance for any tips or suggestions that will help me get to the bottom of this and get it resolved!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by deleting and recreating the member. This process assigned a new member ID and once I updated my code with the new ID the special link begin working for all intended members. This perhaps isn't actually an answer but instead a workaround, nevertheless my problem is resolved! Thanks